# XPages: Rendering combo box in read mode

Tags: xpages

When the page opens in read mode, what code is responsible in showing the "text" as opposed to "alias or saved value" of a combo box? There is some code that loops through the select items and retrieves the text of a matched value to display it in read mode. I think there is no concept of page read mode in JSF. So it must be a XPage implementation. I checked the code in renderers and the converters, still no clue. I am not trying to solve any particular issue here, just wanted to know what converter/renderer does that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the behaviour is the same as it ever was using Notes client I'm sure that this is part of Domino's own data model. The special delimiter used in Notes client coding is the 'pipe' character ('|'). That is, Domino itself is serving everything left of the delimiter as 'text', and everything that's right of it as 'value'